Grooves in Painted Exterior Trim
Paint isn't peeling yet but these grooves look like an invitation for water damage, to me. Paint is 2 years old. It's a long-term rental. Should this be sanded and grooves filled, then painted? Or would that be a waste because the nature or age of this wood will necessitate it needing to be replaced, in the future? If replacing is ineveitable, is there a somewhat easy fix to exted its life? TIA!


Use a pointy thing with your hand and push into the wood.  Rotted wood you can push in more than 1/8 inch.  Not rotted sand, fill and repaint, or replace.  For trim, can replace with PVC or cover with flashing, to save painting.
